# Accuracy of numerical integration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, integral, numerical-integration, significant-digits

I am trying to integrate an analytic function (a composite of sqrt and trig function) on a rectangle area. It has no singularity point in the area and seems to be a perfect candidate to use `dblquad`. My question is how to evaluate the accuracy of the numerical value that Matlab provided to me. Without knowing the exact value of the integration, how can we justify the significant-digits? When you are required to give a value with certain digits of precision, you should be able to justify. Is it possible to achieve this given the value is calculated by using Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you set it otherwise, `dblquad` uses a default tolerance threshold (10<sup>-6</sup> in the latest releases) for the absolute quadrature error. The approximation of the integral will be within an error no larger than the specified tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a peek at the source code for `dblquad`, somewhere it will be using a certain number of 'steps'. I guess you could make a new m-file with the important bits that get the integral working and play around with the number of steps until it takes the computer a long time and doesn't change the result. Personally I use a custom simpsons rule for numerical integration and just change N (number of steps) to some large number.